# Parse an XML with multiple elements using Python with sax

Tags: python, xml, sax

I am trying to parse an XML file with Python using SAX.

The document has multiple elements with the same name. I want to print some of the attributes of the elements, but the program just prints the attributes of the last element encountered in the document.

This is the code:

```
# art.py
import sys

from xml.sax import make_parser 
from handlers import ArticleHandler

ch = ArticleHandler( ) 
saxparser = make_parser( )

saxparser.setContentHandler(ch)
saxparser.parse(sys.stdin)

print "TYPE:", ch.TYPE
print "SUBTYPE:" , ch.SUBTYPE


# handlers.py
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class ArticleHandler(ContentHandler):

 TYPE = ""
 SUBTYPE = ""

 def startElement(self, name, attrs):
     if name == "relation":
         self.TYPE = attrs.get("TYPE", "") 
         self.SUBTYPE = attrs.get("SUBTYPE")
```

This is the XML:

```
    <relation ID="CNN_CF_20030303.1900.00-R3" TYPE="ORG-AFF" SUBTYPE="Employment">
    ...
    </relation>
    <relation ID="CNN_CF_20030303.1900.00-R4" TYPE="ORG-AFF" SUBTYPE="Membership">
    ...
    </relation>
```

For this input the output is

```
    TYPE:ORG-AFF
    SUBTYPE:Membership
```

whereas the expected output is

```
    TYPE:ORG-AFF
    SUBTYPE:Employment
    TYPE:ORG-AFF
    SUBTYPE:Membership
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: I'm not very good at python, but it seems your program call ArticleHandler.startElement for each tag in the xml file that assigns their properties to the fields of the ArticleHandler object. So, if you have a lot of tags it will reassign fields. And in the end of parsing you just print properties of last tag was parsed.

Comment: Why would you want to use SAX? Even if you have memory limitations preventing any DOM approach, there are far better APIs. See the `iterparse` functions in lxml, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rewrite your program to handle multiple relation tags, e.g. by using a list

```
import sys
from xml.sax import make_parser 
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class ArticleHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.relations = []

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == "relation":
            self.relations.append((attrs.get("TYPE", ""), attrs.get("SUBTYPE"))

ch = ArticleHandler() 
saxparser = make_parser()
saxparser.setContentHandler(ch)
saxparser.parse(sys.stdin)

for type, subtype in ch.relations:
    print "TYPE:", type
    print "SUBTYPE:" , subtype
```